# cannot create jms topic in jboss 6.0.1 using cli interface on cluster environment

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jboss6.x

I am trying to create the jms-topic in JBOSS 6.0.1 version using command line interface of jboss .
I am able to do it on standalone server but issues arises when i run command on cluster environment.
Here is what i do:
Standalone server command:

```
jms-topic add --topic-address=java:/com.matrix.jms.samp.imp.solution.topic.ReplyTopic --entries=java:/com.matrix.jms.samp.imp.solution.topic.ReplyTopic
```

Exectues succesfully

Now when i run same command on cluster environment of jboss it ask me to give **profile**. I give profile and execute this command:

```
jms-topic add --profile=hornetq-server --topic-address=java:/com.matrix.jms.samp.imp.solution.topic.ReplyTopic --entries=java:/com.matrix.jms.samp.imp.solution.topic.ReplyTopic
```

It gives me following error,

```
    JBAS014766: Resource [("profile" => "hornetq-server")] does not exist; a resource at address [
    ("profile" => "hornetq-server"),
    ("subsystem" => "messaging"),
    ("hornetq-server" => "default"),
    ("jms-topic" => "java:/com.matrix.jms.samp.imp.solution.topic.ReplyTopic")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added
```

Is my profile name wrong . I am able to create topic from jboss management console.
Please suggest

Comment: Check on your domain.xml for <profiles> and be sure there is one profile named hornetq-server. By defualt you have **default**, **ha**, **full** and **full-ha** support for hornetq is on **full* and **full-ha**

Comment: Right Yesterday i checked profile in domain.xml and i found rigth profile. Thanks for pointing it out +1